# Python TypeError - required bytes-like object instead of str

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, typeerror

I'm trying to pass some JSON objects and two integers to a pool.

```
for i in range(0, multiprocessing.cpu_count()-1):
    fromindex = i * chunklen
    toindex = (i+1) * chunklen
    chunkedData.append([data['features'][fromindex:toindex], weekdaytopredict, hourtopredict])
chunkedData.append([data['features'][toindex:], weekdaytopredict, hourtopredict])
parallelstart = time.time()
result = (pool.map(parallelUpdateWithDT, chunkedData))
```

`data` is a geoJSON file with some polygons. I'd like to distribute these polygons for parallel processing. I pass `n/cpu_count()` polygons to the `parallelUpdateWithDT` function, which should further process them. My problem is a typeerror: Even though `print(chunkedData)` returns `<class 'list'>`, I geth the following error: `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`. Where am I messing this up? Full stack trace:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RemoteTraceback                           Traceback (most recent call last)
RemoteTraceback: 
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 119, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 44, in mapstar
    return list(map(*args))
  File "<ipython-input-114-bf56cacb90b9>", line 34, in parallelUpdateWithDT
    if('rain' in result):
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-115-031a5e24ee66> in <module>()
----> 1 decisionTreePrediciton(3, 5)

<ipython-input-114-bf56cacb90b9> in decisionTreePrediciton(weekdaytopredict, hourtopredict)
     15     print (type(chunkedData))
     16 
---> 17     result = (pool.map(parallelUpdateWithDT, chunkedData))
     18     parallelend = time.time()
     19 

/usr/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/pool.py in map(self, func, iterable, chunksize)
    258         in a list that is returned.
    259         '''
--> 260         return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
    261 
    262     def starmap(self, func, iterable, chunksize=None):

/usr/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/pool.py in get(self, timeout)
    606             return self._value
    607         else:
--> 608             raise self._value
    609 
    610     def _set(self, i, obj):
```

A sample of `chunkedData`:

```
[[[{'geometry': {'coordinates': [[[10.914622377957983, 45.682007076150505], [10.927456267537572, 45.68179119797432], [10.927147329501077, 45.672795442796335], [10.914315493899755, 45.67301125363092], [10.914622377957983, 45.682007076150505]]], 'type': 'Polygon'}, ///////////////////////etc, waaay too big////////////, 'id': 6574, 'properties': {'cellId': 11454}}], 3, 5]
```

How is this an `str`? I don't get it. Thanks for any help!

Comment: The worker raised an error at `if('rain' in result):` and that was propagated back to the parent and re-raised there to let it know what happened. The problem is in the worker code that isn't posted here. I'm guessing `result` is a calculated value not in the chunk. You could add `print(repr(result))` just above that line and see what you get. But since the bug is in code not posted, we can't say too much about it.

Answer (score 3):

It's impossible to tell from the code you posted, but I suspect that you are trying to check if a `str` is `in` a `bytes`.  For example:

```
>>> bytes_obj = b'result'
>>> 'res' in bytes_obj
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

This implies that `result` in your code is of type `bytes`.  There are two resolutions here.  The first is to make `'rain'` into a bytes object too:

```
if b'rain' in result:
    ...
```

The second is to turn `result` into a `str`:

```
result = result.decode(whatever_codec_it_should_be)
```

If you're going to take this second approach, you should convert result into a `str` at the earliest possible moment to avoid all sorts of `str` vs. `bytes` headaches.  Usually, if you don't *know* you need a different codec, most things work off of `utf-8` these days, so you could try that one...